# Remove automatic display in octave

Tags: command-line, octave

I want to convert java matrix to octave matrix. To that end, I use the function http://information-dynamics-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/octave/javaMatrixToOctave.m which works fine.
The only issue is that the line

```
octaveMatrix = tmp.ident(tmp);
```

prints on the command line the following text

```
[ (2 by 2) array of double ]
```

I would like to be able to prevent this to happen. But how?

Comment: I think we would need to know what `tmp` is, and what the function `tmp.ident()` looks like...

Comment: If you follow the link, you'll find what tmp is. ident() is a method of object org.octave.Matrix, but I have no clue of what it does...

Comment: @Antoine this seems to be very specific to dynamics-toolkit and you're unlikely to get any help unless you can be clearer or give others a way to reproduce your issue. If you end your commands with `;`, you should get nothing displayed. If you do, that's likely a dynamics-toolkit bug and there's nothing you can do about it short of changing its code.